# A convenient wrapper for Telegram Bot library

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

I'm working on several projects involving Telegram bots and I've decided to make a library that meets my needs. Basically, there is already a Python [library for Telegram bots](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) (`import telegram` in my code), but I wanted to wrap it to make it even more convenient to me.

In terms of functionality it works fine. But I'm a self-educated programmer, so I realize that my code often lacks consistency and readability. That's why I'm here, looking for advices on how to understand how to write the code efficiently.

Any critique is welcome, regarding formatting, more efficient and fast code flow, or whatever; and here are the specific questions that concern me:

1. I use PyCharm and it suggests me to make some methods in class static. For example, `breakLongMessage()`, `isDocument()`, `isPhoto()`. As I understand, it is because they don't use anything from within the class, so they are instance-independent (I might be wrong). Is making them `@staticmethod` really beneficial? Maybe, memory usage is better?
2. I can pass several functions to my main loop, specified in `start()`. Their roles are described in the code (I hope I wrote it fine). But sometimes I may not need, for example, `termination_function`. I thought about passing `None` as a default parameter, but `None` is not callable, so I pass an empty `dummyFunction` which does nothing. Maybe I can do it better somehow instead?
3. There is a `MAX_CHARS_PER_MESSAGE` parameter which I want to remain constant. But I had an urge to put it into the class as a static variable. Is it an acceptable practice to use global variables from outside a class in the class?
4. Errors happen, and my code handles them and prints them. But I need a way for it to print detailed data on an error. I mean, when I run a code in terminal and it encounters an error (outside `try...except...`), it prints it in a very detailed manner, with a full tree of functions, files and line numbers leading to the error. I've been browsing the web and the best I could find was `sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno` which I use, for example, in my `sendMessage()`. It is far from being detailed and does not lead me to where this error actually happened. Is there some way to recieve and print a detailed error log when it is caught and `except:...` is triggered?
5. Methods like `isDocument()`, `isPhoto()` and `markup()` (contained in `sendMessage()` are very simple, they just have some `if...elif...else...` statements with one operation. I've seen people writing one-operation statements in a single line, like I did here. PyCharm doesn't like it at all and shows warnings. So I want to know, is it better in terms of code consistency and readability to write such statements on separate lines, or is it okay to leave them like this?
6. I often see people use `_` and `__` in their classes. But I still can't understand how they determine whether a method should be public, private or "weakly-private" (I'm not sure what a single underscore does). Looking for recommendations in this affair as well.
7. PyCharm formats docstrings automatically for me. As I understand, it is **reST** syntax. It's said to be widely used, but there are competitors? Should I stick to it or it is better to use some other docstring syntax?
8. Since Python is not strict about types, I think I need to specify the types of arguments and return values. Should I write it plainly in `:param x:` and `:return:`?
9. I tend to use `while True` with breaks, especially in functions that rely on connection to some external server, downloading/uploading functions, etc., but people often tell that using `while True` with breaks is a bad practice. If so, what can I replace them with?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -u
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
import telegram
import socket
from os import path, makedirs
import sys
from time import sleep

# if a connection is lost and getUpdates takes too long, an error is raised
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)

# logging settings to make them more readable and informative
logging.basicConfig(format=u'[%(asctime)s] %(filename)s[LINE:%(lineno)d]# %(levelname)-8s  %(message)s',
                    level=logging.WARNING)

############
# PARAMETERS
############

MAX_CHARS_PER_MESSAGE = 2048


##########
# METHODS
#########

def dummyFunction(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Does nothing, used as a placeholder
    :return: None
    """
    pass


############
# CLASSES###
############


class telegramHigh:
    """
    telegramHigh is a library that helps handling Telegram bots in Python.
    """

    def __init__(self, token):
        """

        :param token: Telegram bot token. Can be received from BotFather.
        :return: None
        """
        super(telegramHigh, self).__init__()
        # an identifier of the last update object.
        self.LAST_UPDATE_ID = None
        # Initialize bot
        self.bot = telegram.Bot(token)

    @staticmethod
    def isPhoto(update):
        """
        Returns true if the given message is a Photo.
        :param update: an update object containing a message.
        :return: True or False
        """
        try:
            if update.message.photo: return True
            else: return False
        except AttributeError:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def isDocument(update):
        """
        Returns true if the given message is a Document (a File).
        :param update: an update object containing a message.
        :return: True or False
        """
        try:
            if update.message.document: return True
            else: return False
        except AttributeError:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def breakLongMessage(msg):
        """
        Breaks a message that is too long.
        :param msg: message to be split
        :return: a list of message pieces
        """

        # let's split the message by newlines first
        result_split = msg.split("\n")

        # the result will be stored here
        broken = []

        # splitting routine
        while result_split:
            result = ""
            while True:
                if result_split:
                    result += result_split.pop(0) + "\n"
                else:
                    break
                if len(result) > MAX_CHARS_PER_MESSAGE:
                    break

            if result:
                n_parts = int(len(result) / MAX_CHARS_PER_MESSAGE + 1)

                for i in range(n_parts):
                    broken += [result[i * len(result) // n_parts:(i + 1) * len(result) // n_parts]]

        return broken

    def sendMessage(self, chat_id, message, key_markup="SAME", preview=True, markdown=False, reply_to=None):
        """
        Sends a text message to Telegram user
        :param chat_id: ID of chat
        :param message: text to send
        :param key_markup: a list representing a custom keyboard markup to show to user.
        If "SAME", use the same markup as before.
        If None, hide the custom keyboard.
        :param preview: Should a link in a message generate a page preview within a message?
        :param markdown: Should a message support markdown formatting?
        :param reply_to: An id of an existing message. A sent message will be a reply to that message.
        :return: None
        """
        def markup(m):
            if not m: return telegram.ReplyKeyboardHide()
            elif m == "SAME": return None
            else: return telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(m)

        logging.warning("Replying to " + str(chat_id) + ": " + message)
        fulltext = self.breakLongMessage(message)
        for text in fulltext:
            # iterating over parts of a long split message
            while True:
                try:
                    if text:
                        self.bot.sendChatAction(chat_id, telegram.ChatAction.TYPING)
                        self.bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id,
                                            text=text,
                                            parse_mode='Markdown' if markdown else None,
                                            disable_web_page_preview=(not preview),
                                            reply_markup=markup(key_markup),
                                            reply_to_message_id=reply_to
                                            )
                except Exception as e:
                    if "Message is too long" in str(e):
                        self.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, message="Error: Message is too long!")
                    elif ("urlopen error" in str(e)) or ("timed out" in str(e)):
                        logging.error("Could not send message. Retrying! Error: " + str(
                                sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno) + ": " + str(e))
                        sleep(3)
                        continue
                    else:
                        logging.error(
                                "Could not send message. Error: " + str(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno) + ": " + str(e))
                break

    def sendPic(self, chat_id, pic, caption=None):
        """
        Sends a picture in a Telegram message to a user. Retries if fails.
        :param chat_id: ID of chat
        :param pic: a picture file. Preferably the object created with open()
        :param caption: a text that goes together with picture ina message.
        :return: None
        """
        while True:
            try:
                logging.debug("Picture: " + str(pic))
                self.bot.sendChatAction(chat_id, telegram.ChatAction.UPLOAD_PHOTO)
                # set file read cursor to the beginning.
                # This ensures that if a file needs to be re-read (may happen due to exception), it is read from the beginning.
                pic.seek(0)
                self.bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=chat_id, photo=pic, caption=caption)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(
                        "Could not send picture. Retrying! Error: " + str(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno) + ": " + str(e))
                sleep(1)
                continue
            break

    def getUpdates(self):
        """
        Gets updates. Updates are basically messages sent to bot from users.
        Retries if it fails.
        :return: a list of update objects
        """
        # if getting updates fails - retry
        updates = []
        while True:
            try:
                updates = self.bot.getUpdates(offset=self.LAST_UPDATE_ID)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error("Could not read updates. Retrying! Error: " +
                            str(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno) + ": " + str(e))
                sleep(1)
                continue
            break
        return updates

    def getFileID(self, update, photoIndex=-1):
        """
        Gets the file_id of a file contained in a message. Empty string if there is no file.
        :param update: update object containing a message.
        :param photoIndex: a photo message contains a picture in various resolutions.
        This determines which one should be picked.
        By default it is the last one, which has the highest resolution.
        :return: file_id
        """
        if self.isPhoto(update):
            file_id = update.message.photo[photoIndex]['file_id']
        elif self.isDocument(update):
            file_id = update.message.document['file_id']
        else:
            file_id = ""

        return file_id

    def getFileByID(self, file_id):
        """
        Gets a `File` object based on file_id.
        :param file_id:
        :return: `File`
        """
        return self.bot.getFile(file_id)

    def getFileByUpdate(self, update, photoIndex=-1):
        """
        Gets a `File` object based on update object.
        :param update: update object containing a message.
        :param photoIndex: a photo message contains a picture in various resolutions.
        This determines which one should be picked.
        By default it is the last one, which has the highest resolution.
        :return: `File`
        """
        file_id = self.getFileID(update, photoIndex)
        return self.getFileByID(file_id)

    def getFullPath(self, update, photoIndex=-1):
        """
        Gets a full path (URL) of a file contained in a message.
        :param update: update object containing a message.
        :param photoIndex: a photo message contains a picture in various resolutions.
        This determines which one should be picked.
        By default it is the last one, which has the highest resolution.
        :return: full URL path to file
        """
        File = self.getFileByUpdate(update, photoIndex)
        pth = File.file_path
        return pth

    def getFullName(self, update, photoIndex=-1):
        """
        Gets a filename (with extension) which is assigned by Telegram to a file contained in a message.
        :param update: update object containing a message.
        :param photoIndex: a photo message contains a picture in various resolutions.
        This determines which one should be picked.
        By default it is the last one, which has the highest resolution.
        :return: full neame of a file
        """
        pth = self.getFullPath(update, photoIndex)
        full_name = path.basename(pth)
        return full_name

    def getURLFileName(self, update, photoIndex=-1):
        """
        Gets a filename (without extension) which is assigned by Telegram to a file contained in a message.
        :param update: update object containing a message.
        :param photoIndex: a photo message contains a picture in various resolutions.
        This determines which one should be picked.
        By default it is the last one, which has the highest resolution.
        :return: file name without extension
        """
        full_name = self.getFullName(update, photoIndex)
        file_name = path.splitext(full_name)[0]
        return file_name

    def getFileExt(self, update, photoIndex=-1, no_dot=False):
        """
        Gets a filename (without extension) which is assigned by Telegram to a file contained in a message.
        :param update: update object containing a message.
        :param photoIndex: a photo message contains a picture in various resolutions.
        This determines which one should be picked.
        By default it is the last one, which has the highest resolution.
        :param no_dot: removes a dot from file extension if True.
        :return: file extension
        """
        pth = self.getFullPath(update, photoIndex)
        file_ext = path.splitext(pth)[1]
        if no_dot:
            file_ext = file_ext.replace(".", "")
        return file_ext

    @staticmethod
    def getDocumentFileName(update):
        """
        Returns a filename (with extension) of a document (File) in a message. 
        It is the original name of a file, not the one that Telegram assigns to files.
        Works only for file messages (not photo, text, etc.)
        :param update: an update object containing a message
        :return: a filename (with extension). Or empty string if update is not a document
        """
        try:
            document = update.message.document
            if document:
                return document["file_name"]
            else:
                return ""
        except AttributeError:
            return ""

    def getFileSize(self, update):
        """
        Returns the size of a file in a message.
        :param update: an update object containing a message
        :return: file size
        """

        file_id = self.getFileID(update)
        File = self.getFileByID(file_id)
        file_size = File['file_size']
        return file_size

    def downloadFile(self, file_id, custom_filepath=None):
        """
        Downloads the file with the given file_id to a specified location.
        It can be from any type of message (Photo, Document, etc.)
        :param file_id:
        :param custom_filepath: A full path where a file should be saved.
        If nothing is specified, it will be saved to current folder with a name that Telegram assigned to it.
        Note: the extension specified in custom_filepath is ignored.
        It is assigned automatically depending on the original extension (Document)
        or the one Telegram assigned to a file (Photo)
        :return: None
        """
        File = self.bot.getFile(file_id)
        if custom_filepath:
            # finding out the extension of an image file on Telegram server
            file_name_with_path, file_ext = path.splitext(File.file_path)
            # directory path to save image to
            directory = path.dirname(custom_filepath)
            # gluing together a filepath and extension, overriding one specified in arguments
            custom_filepath = path.splitext(custom_filepath)[0] + file_ext
            # create a directory if it doesn't exist
            if directory:
                makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
        # download the file to a given directory
        File.download(custom_path=custom_filepath)

    def start(self, processingFunction=dummyFunction, periodicFunction=dummyFunction,
            termination_function=dummyFunction, slp=0.1):
        """
        Starts the main loop, which can handle termination on `KeyboardInterrupt` (e.g. Ctrl+C)
        :param processingFunction: a function that is invoked in a current iteration of the loop
        only if there are updates. An `update` argument containing a message object is passed to it.
        :param periodicFunction: a function that is invoked in every iteration of the loop
        regardless of presence of updates.
        :param termination_function: a function that is invoked when the loop is terminated by user.
        :param slp: a pause between loops to decrease load.
        :return: None
        """
        while True:
            try:
                # a function that is called regardless of updates' presence
                periodicFunction()
                self.updateProcessing(processingFunction=processingFunction)
                sleep(slp)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Terminated by user!")
                termination_function()

                # this ensures that LAST_UPDATE_ID is updated
                #  or else it will process already processed messages after restart
                self.getUpdates()
                break

    def updateProcessing(self, processingFunction=dummyFunction):
        """
        This function gets updates, passes them to `processingFunction` and updates the LAST_UPDATE_ID.
        :param processingFunction: a function that is invoked in a current iteration of the loop
        only if there are updates. An `update` argument containing a message object is passed to it.
        :return: None
        """

        # basically, messages sent to bot
        updates = self.getUpdates()

        # main message processing routine
        for update in updates:
            logging.warning("Received message: " + str(
                    update.message.chat_id) + " " + update.message.from_user.username + " " + update.message.text)

            # a functions that processes updates, one by one
            processingFunction(update)

            # Updates global offset to get the new updates
            self.LAST_UPDATE_ID = update.update_id + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just answering your numbered questions.

1. Static methods are necessary in languages like Java where everything has to be part of a class. But in Python you can just write a function, and so `@staticmethod` is never necessary, and rarely helpful.
2. `dummyFunction` is fine, but I think many Python programmers would prefer to use `None` as the default value and write:

   ```
   if periodicFunction is not None:
       periodicFunction()
   ```

   The reasons for preferring this, even though the implementation has to be slightly more wordy, are (i) it's very common in Python for optional arguments to default to `None`, and so this is easier for the reader to understand; (ii) sometimes you need to explicitly request the default behaviour, and then it's easy to supply the `None`.

   See for example [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread), where:

   > *target* is the callable object to be invoked by the `run()` method. Defaults to `None`, meaning nothing is called.
3. Since `MAX_CHARS_PER_MESSAGE` is only used by `breakLongMessage`, it would be simplest to make it an optional argument to that function:

   ```
   def breakLongMessage(msg, max_len=2048):
       """Split the string msg into pieces that are no longer than
       max_len and return them as a list.
       """
   ```

   This keeps related code together, improves the documentation, and makes the function easier to test (because you can pass in small values for `max_len` to keep the tests and their results readable).
4. Use the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module to format stack traces.
5. The reason why it's good to keep statements on separate lines is because many Python introspection tools use line numbers. (i) Python stack traces only tell you the line number where the exception happened, so if there are multiple statements on a line, you won't know which one raised the exception; (ii) the Python debugger only lets you set a breakpoint on the first statement on a line, so that if you write `if condition: statement`, then you won't be able to set a breakpoint on `statement`; (iii) Python tracing, profiling and coverage tools are line-based.

   But, in this particular case, instead of:

   ```
   if update.message.document: return True
   else: return False
   ```

   you can write:

   ```
   return bool(update.message.document)
   ```
6. The `_` and `__` prefixes don't have anything to do with the concepts of *public* and *private* in languages like Java. All methods in Python are public, but there's a [convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) whereby an initial single underscore is used to mean "method that's not intended for use outside of the class". But it's just a convention: the language itself does nothing to enforce it.

   The double underscore prefix has a particular use case: to allow a class to be sure that a method name won't collide with a method name in some other class, when the two classes are combined via inheritance. If this use case doesn't apply to you, then don't use the double underscore. (The double underscore doesn't make the method private: it just causes the compiler to translate the name so that it's unique; you can still call it via its transformed name.)
7. There's no standard format for docstrings. There are several tools that automatically process docstrings into documentation ([pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html), [autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html), [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), etc.), and they have different formats. Use the format for your preferred documentation-processing tool.
8. Yes, it's a good idea to document the types of function arguments and results.
9. There's nothing wrong with using `while True:` and `break`. Here's [Raymond Hettinger on the subject](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-October/554366.html):

   > Like you, I use `while True` often.  We use it frequently in the standard library and have no PEP 8 admonition against it, nor does pychecker report it as a negative practice. The use of `while 1` loops has a long history in other languages as well.
   >
   > So, if you hear someone make-up a new "best practice" proscribing `while True`, just smile and continue to write programs as you have been.  You will not be alone.  Many excellent programmers write `while True` whenever it is called for.

Comment: About 2: I've just thought that I could also use `processingFunction=lambda: None`, which is a simpler replacement. That way I need neither an auxiliary function nor a conditional statement.